# CORS問題が解決しない

Tags: go, cors

フロントはTypescriptとVue3、サーバーサイドはgo言語を使って実装しています。
フロントからサーバー側のAPIを叩いた際に以下のエラーが発生しており、サーバー側でCORSの設定を行ったんですが、こちらのエラーが解決しません。
分かる方いますでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/price/?money_received=350000&bouns=1000000&fixed_cost=120000&loan=43000&private=55000' from origin 'http://localhost:4173' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

go側のソースを張っておきます。

- server/controllers/price_management_controllers.go

```
// controllers/price_management_controllers.go
package controllers

import (
    "net/http"
    "server/common"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

type PriceInfo struct {
    LeftAmount  int `json:"left_amount"`
    TotalAmount int `json:"total_amount"`
}

type Response struct {
    PriceInfo PriceInfo `json:"result"`
}

func priceCalc(moneyReceived, bouns, fixedCost, loan, private int) PriceInfo {

    var priceinfo PriceInfo
    priceinfo.LeftAmount = moneyReceived - fixedCost - loan - private
    priceinfo.TotalAmount = (priceinfo.LeftAmount * 12) + bouns

    return priceinfo
}

func GetPriceInfo(c *gin.Context) {
    data, err := common.IntgetPrameter(c, "money_received", "bouns", "fixed_cost", "loan", "private")

    if err == nil {
        res := priceCalc(data["money_received"], data["bouns"], data["fixed_cost"], data["loan"], data["private"])

        response := Response{PriceInfo: res}

        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"message": response})
    } else {
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"message": err})
    }

}

func CreateUser(c *gin.Context) {
    // ユーザーの作成ロジック
    c.JSON(http.StatusCreated, gin.H{"message": "User created"})
}
```

- server/routes/routes.go

```
// routes/routes.go
package routes

import (
    "server/controllers"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func SetupRoutes(r *gin.Engine) {
    Routes := r.Group("/api")
    {
        Routes.GET("/price", controllers.GetPriceInfo)
        // Routes.POST("/", controllers.CreateUser)
    }
}
```

- server/main.go

```
// main.go
package main

import (
    "server/routes"

    "github.com/gin-contrib/cors" // corsミドルウェアのインポート
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()
    // CORSミドルウェアを追加
    config := cors.DefaultConfig()
    config.AllowOrigins = []string{"*"}
    config.AllowMethods = []string{"GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"}
    r.Use(cors.New(config))
    routes.SetupRoutes(r)
    r.Run(":8080")
}
```

Comment: Fiddler などのツールを使って要求・応答をキャプチャしてその中身を見て、CORS に必要なヘッダがやり取りされているか調べてください。Fiddler で見ればこの記事の 2 つ目の画像のような情報が得られるはずです⇒ http://surferonwww.info/BlogEngine/post/2023/01/21/aspnet-core-web-api-with-cors-middle-ware.aspx

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
確認してみます